# How can I replace the <title> element in many HTML files?

Tags: html, html-parsing

My directory `~/foo` contains many HTML files. Each one has a different unwanted `title` element. That is, each file contains the code

```html
<title>something unwanted</title>
```

Many of these files also contain some `span` elements like this

```html
<span class="org-document-info-keyword">#+Title:</span> 
<span class="org-document-title">correct title</span>
```

I'd like to write a script that scans each HTML file and, for each file that contains a code-block of the second type, replaces the unwanted `title` with the correct title.

Once the title has been replaced, I'd like the script to remove the code in the second block.

For example, running the script on

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!-- Created by htmlize-1.47 in css mode. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo.org</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
      body {
        color: #839496;
        background-color: #002b36;
      }
      .org-document-info {
        /* org-document-info */
        color: #839496;
      }
      .org-document-info-keyword {
        /* org-document-info-keyword */
        color: #586e75;
      }
      .org-document-title {
        /* org-document-title */
        color: #93a1a1;
        font-size: 130%;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .org-level-1 {
        /* org-level-1 */
        color: #cb4b16;
        font-size: 130%;
      }

      a {
        color: inherit;
        background-color: inherit;
        font: inherit;
        text-decoration: inherit;
      }
      a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
      }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
<span class="org-document-info-keyword">#+Title:</span> <span class="org-document-title">my desired title
</span><span class="org-document-info-keyword">#+Date:</span> <span class="org-document-info">&lt;2015-08-23 Sun&gt;
</span>
<span class="org-level-1">* hello world</span>

Vivamus id enim.  

</pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

should result in

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<!-- Created by htmlize-1.47 in css mode. -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my desired title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      <!--
      body {
          color: #839496;
          background-color: #002b36;
      }
      .org-document-info {
          /* org-document-info */
          color: #839496;
      }
      .org-document-info-keyword {
          /* org-document-info-keyword */
          color: #586e75;
      }
      .org-document-title {
          /* org-document-title */
          color: #93a1a1;
          font-size: 130%;
          font-weight: bold;
      }
      .org-level-1 {
          /* org-level-1 */
          color: #cb4b16;
          font-size: 130%;
      }

      a {
          color: inherit;
          background-color: inherit;
          font: inherit;
          text-decoration: inherit;
      }
      a:hover {
          text-decoration: underline;
      }
    -->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre>
      <span class="org-document-info-keyword">#+Date:</span> <span class="org-document-info">&lt;2015-08-23 Sun&gt;
      </span>
      <span class="org-level-1">* hello world</span>

      Vivamus id enim.  

    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas what HTML parser would work well for this job?

Comment: Can you show the file before and then what you expect it to look like after.

Comment: I have never used `HTML::Manipulator` myself or seen it used anywhere. Your question is unclear. It sounds like you want to replace the string in `title` with the text in a `span` element that has a class of `org-document-title`. But I don't see why you're showing another `span` element with a different class attribute. It will help you a lot if you show a minimal HTML document with the corresponding translation that you want. Is your document formal XHTML or may it be a lax interpretation?

Comment: @Borodin I displayed the other `span` element because I want the script to delete that particular element. I will post a minimal working example shortly. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick: It sounds like the `<span>` should have been a `<div>`. Depending on the source of the document it may not be possible to parse it and perform the transforms that you want. Your first step should be to find an HTML parser that will round-trip all of your documents -- from text to internal representation and back again -- *without* any changes but with acceptable results

Comment: @Borodin My HTML files are generated using the `htmlize` feature in `emacs`.

Comment: Depends on your IDE. Many IDEs allow to search and replace.

Comment: @JonasDralle: *What* depends on my IDE? Are you addressing Brian or myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is one way to do it Python.

```py
import sys
from lxml import etree
from lxml.html import parse
doc = parse(sys.argv[1])
title = doc.find('//title')
span1 = doc.find('//span[@class="org-document-info-keyword"]')
span2 = doc.find('//span[@class="org-document-title"]')
title.text = span2.text.strip()
span1.getparent().remove(span1)
span2.getparent().remove(span2)
print etree.tostring(doc)
```

You can put that into a file called `script.py` and then to run it on an HTML source file `foo.html` and write the results to `new-foo.html`, do this:

```
python script.py foo.html > new-foo.html
```

Comment: Great answer! Out of curiosity, do you know where I can find goo documentation on parsing HTML with python?

Comment: The docs on using lxml for parsing HTML are pretty good http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Comment: Running this script on my example changes the `<` on line 6 to `&lt;`. Any idea why?

Comment: The reason the `<` inside the `<style>` element in the input/source is changed to `&lt;` in the output is: Within a `<style>` or `<script>` element, even if there’s something that *looks like* an HTML comment, such a `<!-- foo -->`, the parser doesn’t actually parse it as a comment, and doesn’t put it into the DOM as a comment node. Instead, it just sees that  `<!-- foo -->` as normal text, and normal text inside HTML docs isn’t allowed to contain `<` characters. So when the `.tostring()` call stringifies/serializes the DOM of the document, it emits an `&lt;` entity instead of a literal `<`.

Comment: Is there a way to modify the script to either not do this or to remove the lines in the head containing `<!--` and `-->` altogether?

Comment: I don’t think there’s a way to have lxml emit a literal `<` there rather than `&lt;`. But if you just want to remove the `<!--` and `-->`, you can do that using something like `style = doc.find('//style')` then `style.text = style.text.replace('<!--','')` and `style.text = style.text.replace('-->','')` (before you use `tostring()` to re-serialize/output the doc).